# How to report "scraping" sites, copying SFSE content?

Tags: support

Not sure Meta is the right place for this, but I have stumbled upon https://salesforce.forumming.com/ which obviously copies posts from SFSE, alters the posters' names, and shows no references to SFSE whatsoever.
Few examples:

[Example 1](https://salesforce.forumming.com/question/8122/what-are-quot-super-messages-quot-with-respect-to-marketing-cloud) coming from:
[What are "Super Messages" with respect to Marketing cloud?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/286053/what-are-super-messages-with-respect-to-marketing-cloud/286054)

[Example 2](https://salesforce.forumming.com/question/6005/ssjs-split-string) coming from: [SSJS Split String](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/303884/ssjs-split-string)

I thought this might be worth taking a look at (and stopping).

Comment: Good catch. And it is bigger than SFSE - they have "unix.forumming" and others, and when I randomly chose a question on Unix, I (unsurprisingly) found the same as an original Unix & Linux Stack Exchange question. So it seems they are scraping quite a number of Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Similar discussion [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285043/can-quabr-scraping-be-prevented). TLDR, it likely is a violation based on lack of attribution, but you would (probably) need to file your own takedown requetss.

Comment: In a link from a link from the discussion that Adrian posted is this: https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/ . If that is still in effect, the the site that Lukas posted is violating 4 out of 4 attribution requirements. So I would think/hope that SE does something about it on a "meta" level.

Comment: I have sent an adapted [Standard license violation letter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Standard_license_violation_letter) to the website owner, as well as the GoDaddy abuse email address. Not saying this is expected to have any effect, but worth trying.

Comment: This happens often. My answers often appear in books, youtube videos, etc without any attribution. But I don't have the time nor inclination to try and hunt all of them down. Hopefully someday someone will put a stop to this.